Extend express.js Request type and expose it to consuming applications
I am building a npm module in TypeScript that exposes an Express.js middleware, which adds a custom property to the request object. Since this property is not part of the express Request, I get the expected type error. To sort this out, I added the following declaration file:
// types/express/index.d.ts

declare global {
  namespace Express {
    export interface Request {
      myCustomProperty?: {
        foo: string;
        bar: number;
      };
    }
  }
}

Then, I added the file to the include property in my tsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2022",
    "lib": ["ES2022"],
    "module": "Node16",
    "moduleResolution": "node16",
    "allowJs": false,
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": ["src", "types/**/*.d.ts", "test"]
}

That makes the type error go away within the module. However, when I import it in an express application, req.myCustomProperty is recognized as any. I then realized that the declaration file is not being included in the npm package. How can I make TypeScript include the declaration file in the npm package? Am I missing the point and this is not the way I should make third parties aware of the custom property? As a workaround, I removed the declaration file and added the global definition to the module's entry point (ie, to the source code). This works for both the module and the express application, but I am not sure if this is the right way to do it.
